# How can I make the scope of an object created in setup() global?

Tags: arduino, mqtt, arduino-esp8266

I am using the File/Examples/Adafruit MQTT Library/mqtt_ESP8266 example as a model for my code.  In the example, the mqtt object is created as a global variable, and everything works fine.  However, I need to create the mqtt object in setup(), because the constructor parameters are not known until then.  If I move the constructor call

```
Adafruit_MQTT_Client mqtt(&client, AIO_SERVER, AIO_SERVERPORT, AIO_USERNAME, AIO_KEY);
```

from the global namespace to inside setup(), I can no longer see the *mqtt* variable from inside loop().

I have tried declaring a pointer to *mqtt* in the global namespace, but don't know how to change it to point to the *mqtt* object that is created in setup().  How can I do this?

David

Answer (score 3):

It works the same way as standard C++. You can declare a pointer in the global scope and then use the `new` operator on other scopes to dynamically create an object anywhere you wish.

```c
Adafruit_MQTT_Client *mqtt;

void setup() {
    mqtt = new Adafruit_MQTT_Client(&client, ...);
}
```

Remember to utilize the arrow operator (`->`) instead of the standard dot (`.`) to access an instance's members when it's in the form of a pointer:

```c
void loop() {
    // check connection, other stuff, etc...
    mqtt->sendPacket(...);
}
```

For a complete example (using another library from Adafruit though), see [`Adafruit_NeoPixel/examples/simple_new_operator/simple_new_operator.ino`](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel/blob/master/examples/simple_new_operator/simple_new_operator.ino).